# Why do most radial engines use an odd number of cylinders?

Tags: piston-engine, engine-design, vibration

To help suppress vibration, most *'V'* and *'horizontal'* engines use an ***even number of cylinders*** as closely opposed as possible. Radial engines are well known for excessive vibration. For some reason they nearly always use a ***staggered odd number of cylinders*** that would seem to promote vibration, why?

[image]

Comment: V engines have even number of cylinders by definition.

Comment: @Agent_L, you can get a V5 engine. I've no idea if they're used in aircraft or not but VW use them in cars.

Comment: @Holloway VW calls it "VR engine", not "V engine". It's pretty much a staggered inline (R stands for reihen, meaning inline here), not having much in common with V engines except superficially similar cylinder layout.

Comment: @Agent_L / Holloway - Its always interesting to learn the exceptions to the rule; just when you think you pretty well know a subject completely. Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: By definition, V engines have cylinders arranged in a V.  The V designation has absolutely nothing to do with the number of cylinders.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

An odd number of cylinders is required by the combination of the single-crank radial design, the four-stroke (Otto) work cycle, and the desire to keep the power strokes evenly spaced in time.

To keep the design simple and lightweight, a single-bank radial airplane engine has one crank, which means that the pistons must reach the top of their travel in rotation order. But the four-stroke cycle requires that a piston must reach the top of its travel twice for each power stroke. The only way to promote evenly timed power strokes is to fire every other cylinder in rotation order.

With an even number of cylinders this would require a hesitation or skip in the firing sequence on every rotation as the engine switched between the odd and even cylinders. With an odd number of cylinders the timing is quite naturally smooth. For example, the firing order of an eight-cylinder radial would be

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
*   *   *   *     *   *   *   * *   *   *   *     *   *   *   *
```

while the firing order of a nine-cylinder radial is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
```

If you could watch a radial airplane engine in slow motion you would see that when a cylinder is in its compression stroke, the cylinders on either side of it are in their exhaust strokes, and when a cylinder is beginning its power stroke, the cylinders on either side of it are near to beginning their intake strokes.

Two-stroke radial engines do not need to have an odd number of cylinders.

Comment: +1, couldn't explain it any better. For an example of two-stroke radials with even cylinder count the [Zoche diesels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoche_aero-diesel) come to mind. And to study the motion of a radial in slow motion I recommend the CAD models in the [enginehistory.org](http://enginehistory.org/CAD/PasqualiS/BMW801/BMW801_01.gif) site. Caution: The last link is to an animated GIF which takes some time to load.

Comment: How many cylinders are required in order to have two cylinders fire simultaneously - is it 7 or 9?

Comment: @jwzumwalt: A single-bank single-crank radial can *never* fire two cylinders simultaneously.

Comment: @jwzumwalt infinite cylinders are required.

Comment: `An odd number of cylinders is required by the combination of the single-crank radial design` ....weeeeelll, technically, isn't a flat/boxer twin a "two cylinder radial engine"..?

Comment: @Grimm The Opiner: Infinity is not possible. As the number of cylinders *approaches* infinity, their firing sequence *approaches* simultaneity. - Interestingly, in addition the size of the aircraft approaches the size of the universe, obviating the need to take off.

Comment: @Grimm The Opiner: You may call it a radial. I call my little Briggs&Stratton lawnmower a "one cylinder radial" but that don't make it a simple lightweight airplane engine.

Comment: @Grimm The Opiner: As per my first paragraph, one of the three criteria that forces the odd cylinder count of a traditional radial is the single crank. A boxer twin has two cranks.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Well, whatever kind of twin a BMW motorcycle is then. In bike-land they're generally referred to as boxers because the pistons punch "one-two". I love the single cylinder radial! Not least because it's the only radial engine wherein all cylinders fire at once - made possible because it has a crank per cylinder.

Comment: "if you could watch...": [we can watch a radial airplane engine in slow motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGKXdYCksAQ), showing the firing order too

Comment: So clever!  What a great post.

Comment: "technically, isn't a flat/boxer twin a "two cylinder radial engine"" well no 9assuming you mean the boxer in an alfa): nothing in it is radial.  it is four lines tangent specifically to rectangle, **not** a circle.    lawnmower .. "one cylinder radial" sure, it's perfectly reasonable to call a 1-cyclinder a "radial" - because the one line we can assert is tangent to some circle, it is.  The four lines of a boxer simply are not tangent to a circle, so there isn't even a humorous sense in which it is a "radial".

Comment: The biggest reason for the high vibration level from radials (especially single-row type) is that the entire mass of the crank pin, all the connnecting rods, and all the pistons is circulating around the crankshaft in unison.  Even with a heavy counterweight on the crankshaft (generally the case) the front-back imbalance is inescapable in an engine that can be disassembled for major service.

Comment: Is even timing really important? Isn't it very common to have uneven firing on car/motorcycle engines?

Comment: @user3528438: Yes, a smooth firing order is important for piston aircraft engines. Uneven firing applies a vibration through the same mountings and in the same direction as the main forces of the engine on the aircraft. Any springs or elastic grommets in the engine mounts are compressed by these main forces in exactly the right direction to maximally transmit the pulsing vibration.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri None even firing doesn't imply vibration. Also, all of the V engines non-even firing, so what about Merlin?

Comment: user3528438: I sincerely hope for the sake of humanity that you are asking out of pure curiosity and not because you intend to design an actual airplane.

Answer (score 11):

Surely a 1, 3, 2, 4 [firing order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firing_order) (just like an inline-4) seems possible in theory, but [one of] the issues is the ring camshaft.

> (...) unless there is an odd number of cylinders, the ring cam around the nose of the engine would be unable to provide the inlet valve open - exhaust valve open sequence required by the four-stroke cycle.

Watch the animation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Radial_engine_timing-small.gif (too big to upload here).

Notice the two rings, each with two opposite steps (lobes).

As one step pushes a rod, the opposite step does the same two cylinders down with a delay. If they were an even number, the ring cam would be operating two opposite cylinders simultaneously due to the shared crankshaft mounting.

In other words, the ring cam would be letting in the air/fuel mixture with one of the pistons (in a pair) going up, not down.

Comment: You could solve the camshaft problem with a geared camshaft, but of course, a 1, 3, 2, 4 firing order would not have an even spacing in time, so the engine would run very rough.Either way, an odd number of cylinders is the way to go, +1.

Comment: A single-crank radial with an even cylinder count would be easily serviced by *two* pairs of ring cams, one for the odd cylinders and one for the evens. Similarly, it would have two sets of magnetos, unless it was modern enough to have electronic ignition modules.

Comment: I don’t think the cam has anything to do with it. The cam will simply rotate at half the speed of the crank (or 1/4 the speed with two sets of lobes as in the linked animation) The valves will always be in time with the cylinders. The problem is in evenly spacing the firing order. You simply can’t space them evenly with an even number of cylinders.

Comment: Interestingly, cam plates on radials turn at a speed relative to the crank = 1/no. lobes x 2. On a 9 cyl radial with 4 lobes, the cam plate turns against crank rotation, while a 9 cyl with 5 lobes turns in the same direction as the crank.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to have a smooth firing order for an even number of cylinders so long as the number of cylinders is not a power of two. Simplest example is therefore a six-cylinder radial with a firing order of 1-2-5-6-3-4. Power pulses come alternately every 60 and 180 degrees of crankshaft rotation (work it out). Think of it as two superimposed three-cylinder engines sharing the same crankshaft and rotated 60 degrees from each other. A ten-cylinder similarly would have a firing order of 1-2-5-6-9-10-3-4-7-8, with power pulses alternating between every 36 and 108 degrees  This would actually be quite smooth as the power pulses are not instantaneous and sequentially firing cylinders would have considerable overlap in their power strokes, especially with a 10 cylinder design.

A V-engine analog would be a 12 cylinder with a bank angle of other then 60 degrees.  Since a straight six has perfect primary and secondary balance, so does a V-12 at any bank angle.  Only bank angles that are multiples of 60 give all equally spaced power pulses, but with other bank angles, the engine is still perfectly balanced and smooth, the power pulses just come at gaps that alternate back and forth between two values just like a six, ten or twelve cylinder radial would.

Such a six cylinder radial would have an interesting sound at idle, no doubt. It would have a boomboom-boomboom-boomboom rumble, similar to but faster than the "burble" of a cross-plane V-8, but there would be no uneven "hiccup" as the gaps between both sequential cylinders and cylinder pairs are evenly spaced although different.  At speed, I suspect a 10 cylinder would not sound any different than a 5 cylinder, the sound of sequentially-firing cylinder pairs blurring together.

Engines with a power-of-two number of cylinders truly can't be built to run smooth, as they can't be timed as a set of superimposed engines with an odd number of cylinders since powers-of-two have no odd divisors.  For them, there will always be a gap in sequential power stokes once every two crankshaft rotations that doesn't match any other gap, a "hiccup" that could probably cause a lot of vibration.

Comment: +1 Interesting theory -- timing an even-numbered engine as a set of superimposed odd-numbered engines. This would probably be practical for 6, 10, 14, or even 18 cylinders. A 12-cylinder, however, must be timed as four 3-cylinders, which makes the groups of power strokes 4 adjacent cylinders long, with only 3 groups per rotation. This would probably be noticeably rough. - The problem of not enough groups also appears at 20 (four 5-cyl) cylinders, 24 (eight 3-cyl) cylinders, and other impractically large sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at valve timing figures for a average four stroke and bearing loads this will give a clue as to the firing order and to make sure that only one cylinder would fire at a time and avoid bearing overload. As to vibration you have to have equal reciprocating forces in opposite directions but in the radial this cannot be achieved without some sort of balancing shaft this would take valuable power and increase weight obviously

Answer (score 0):

first of all not all V engines have even number of cylinders. 
Honda RC211V uses a v5 (yepp, 3 cyl on one bank and 2 on the other) engine. i just do not have enough rep yet to answer there.
now, odd number of cylinders in a radial engine is required for 4 stroke engines only.it was well described why. but 2 stroke ones may not have odd numbers. allso if double ended pistons are used (rare engine concept) then it would be possible to fire 2 pistons at the same time.

Comment: Honda has a penchant for odd-number V-engines. The NS500 race bike had a V3 engine (2 up, 1 laid down) and also the MVX250 road bike which had the orientation reversed (1 up, 2 laid down).

Answer (score -1):

A even number of cylinders in one bank of a radial engine just does not work, purely for the fact that each cylinder has to fire once in every two rotations of the engine, as their is only one crank it is impossible to achieve a firing sequence that would work.

The firing sequence on a nine cylinder engine is 1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8, this provides a smooth production of power

Go to YouTube and look up “How a radial engine works”

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! This does not seem to add anything to the existing answers.

Comment: Nor does it meet the standards for an answer. If you want to provide a link to a video, that would be an answer.