# Can anyone tell me more info about this radial engine?

Tags: engine-design

non-aviation expert here doing a project for a friend.

I am trying to learn a little more info about this 3D model radial engine.  I downloaded it off a stock 3D model website, that offered almost no information, specifications, etc included.  After doing some research, I think this is a two stroke, supercharged, 8 cylinder radial engine, with each cylinder firing sequentially: from left to right(not the usual alternating firing order of radial engines).  The kind of engine that would be used for a small aircraft, and possibly from an aircraft that came from the first half of the 20th century.

In the image below, I just need a little help in identifying some of the specs.  If anyone could help me learn a little more information about this engine, such as, type(example: propulsion reciprocating & rotary), dimensions, weight, power rating, operation speed, displacement, materials, etc….i would be forever in your debt!!!!  I apologize if the pictures are not the best, and want to thank you for any help you can provide!
[image: Front on Render]

[image: Looking from Slight Left front-on]

[image: Looking from Slight Right front-on]

[image: Looking from More Left front-on]

[image: Looking from More Right front-on]

[image: Cylinders]

[image: From Rear]

[image: Rotational View]

Comment: Is there any reason you believe this random 3D model is based on an existing engine?

Comment: It looks like a version of this [3D model](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/radial-engine-3d-max/904960) which has no reference to a real life one.

Comment: @Sanchises 

You have a great point! I honestly didn't think of the possibility that the 3d model I am using was a real concept/patent that was actually manufactured, distributed, and used in a number of different applications at some point.

Comment: @Sanchises

however with the exception of applications for model airplanes – and based on my own bias in thinking this particular 3d model might have more in common with an older two stroke radial engine - would you know if this model would be comparable to something like a KHD Dz 700: a two stroke, eight cylinder diesel engine manufactured in the first half of the 1900’s?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @mins  thats it! and yeah, no real life reference.  it be like that sometimes i guess.

Comment: @jerkules Interesting find but that engine is in no way comparable to a normal radial. It's fitted with two opposing pistons to overcome the valve timing issues mentioned in the other question.

Answer (score 9):

It is unlikely to represent a real radial engine because it has an even number of cylinders. For reasons [explained elsewhere in this SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47186/62), radials must always possess an odd number of cylinders.

Comment: There are 2-stroke engines with sequential firing that can have an even number of cylinders, but these are generally seen only in model aircraft sizes, often using cylinders, heads, and pistons from single-cylinder engines -- and I've never been sure how they manage to produce crankcase pressure to force induction unless all the pistons are synchronized to TDC.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, also note this engine has pushrods and rocker arms, so it is not one of the 2-stroke "smokers".

Comment: Very unlikely.  There are uniflow 2-stroke diesels with intake valves, but they use superchargers of one sort or another to provide induction pressure.

Comment: @nielsnielsen

From my research, a radial two stroke engine will have the cylinders fire on every revolution, so having an even number of cylinders is not an issue.

Also after researching a little, it seems like a modern example of what im talking about would be the two stroke Zoche diesel radial.

Comment: @nielsnielsen

With that being said, its been brought to my attention that this particular 3d model radial engine I posted about may not be based on a real concept/patent, however with the exception of applications for model airplanes – and based on my own bias in thinking this particular 3d model might have more in common with an older two stroke radial engine - would you know if this model would be comparable to something like a KHD Dz 700: a two stroke, eight cylinder diesel engine manufactured in the first half of the 1900’s?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @jerkules, I am sorry, I do not.

Comment: @ZeissIkon

with the exception of applications for model airplanes – and based on my own bias in thinking this particular 3d model might have more in common with an older two stroke radial engine - would you know if this model would be comparable to something like a KHD Dz 700: a two stroke, eight cylinder diesel engine manufactured in the first half of the 1900’s?  Things like dimensions, weight, power rating, operation speed, displacement, materials?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @jerkules Can't tell you anything about that KHD -- but there have been very few diesel engines made for aircraft, in part because of temperature limitations (if intake air is too cold, compression can't heat it to ignition temperature and the engine stops working) and in part because aviation fuel distribution is all aimed at high octane gasoline and jet kerosene (the latter of which is used as fuel in the two current aircraft diesels I know of, though they can also run on highway diesel).